# Error '80040e21' Multiple-step operation generated errors

Tags: sql, asp-classic

I have a page that posts to a SQL Server 2008 database and I'm Getting the following error.

Microsoft Cursor Engine error '80040e21'

Multiple-step operation generated errors. Check each status value.

/incConfirm.asp, line 429

The code posts data to a table then re-queries to pick up and order ID for use when data is entered into a second table.

In debugging I can see that the problem is being caused by the order ID not being carried forward.

The code is shown below (with line 469 marked).

This is the first part:

```
Set rsOrder = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
rsOrder.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rsOrder.Open "Orders Order By orderID", cnn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable

rsOrder.AddNew
rsOrder.Fields("orderCustId")           = trim(iCustID)
rsOrder.Fields("orderPayId")            = trim(iPayID)
rsOrder.Fields("orderAddrId")           = trim(iAddrID)
rsOrder.Fields("orderDate")     = Now   
rsOrder.Fields("orderIsComplete")   = 1

rsOrder.Update

bookMark = rsOrder.AbsolutePosition 
rsOrder.Requery 
rsOrder.AbsolutePosition = bookMark

iOrderID = rsOrder.Fields("orderID")    
closeobj(rsOrder)

End Function
```

This is the second (containing line 469):

```
Set rsOrderDetail = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
rsOrderDetail.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rsOrderDetail.Open "OrderDetails Order By detailID", cnn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable

    rsOrderDetail.AddNew
rsOrderDetail.Fields("odrdtOrderId")    = trim(iOrderID) - LINE 469
```

As mentioned iOrderID has no value, hence the error. The puzzling thing is that I've been using this code for some time and it works fine on 2 seperate pages?

Comment: Is `iOrderID` a global variable, or the name of a function?  I ask because there's an `End Function` in the first code snippet, which would cause a local variable to go out of scope.  If it's a global variable, maybe there's another piece of code on this page overwriting the value in `iOrderID`?

Comment: No, it is not the name of a function. The snippet is part of a function (forgot to take the last line out).

Comment: As a thought towards the last comment, I will change the name of the variable and give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually do that like this:

```
rsOrder.Open "select * from Orders where orderid=0", cnn, 1,2
rsOrder.AddNew
rsOrder("orderCustId") = trim(iCustID)
rsOrder("orderPayId") = trim(iPayID)
rsOrder("orderAddrId") = trim(iAddrID)
rsOrder("orderDate") = Now
rsOrder("orderIsComplete") = 1
rsOrder.Update 
iOrderID=rsOrder("iOrderID")
rsOrder.close
```

and then I would run the second part which seems fine.